# create extended navigation bar ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

i want to extended navigation like android Android Material extended toolbar when scroll up

[image]

first i create header with 240 high add on it  UILabel at high 24  and  UIImageView for my UITableView

i overrided scrollViewDidScroll

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {


    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if offsetY > myHeader - myLableY{
        print(offsetY)
        self.navTitle.text = "My App Name"


    }else{

        self.navTitle.text = ""

    }



}
```

but i face two problem

1- if number of cells item on uitableview is fewer, can't scroll top of view to change navbar title

2- second when scroll down it show white space i want to tableview head to be parallax

Comment: The thing you are seeing is not a navigation bar that is  extending, it is the header view of the table that is customising its frame. See the scroll bar on the right side when u do scroll the table view.

Comment: what's happening is when you start scrolling, you are hiding the nav bar title and making the ceontent on header view appear larger by fading it in, and do the reverse for collapse action.

Comment: i dont have idea how to  create extend navigation bar , so i try to use uitableview header to do this , i but this code to show my solution but i get problem with this solution.

Comment: i have UILabel and UIImage on  uitableview header  it's display app name and app logo but in large size ,header height is 240

Comment: You can refer to [iOS 11 navigation bar height customizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387285/ios-11-navigation-bar-height-customizing)