# UINavigationBar height not changed IOS 11 after update Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have changed the navigation bar height this way:

```
extension UINavigationBar {
  override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 72)
  }
}
```

After updating to Xcode 9 and iOS 11 it is not working. Please anyone help to fix that issue.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325181/ios-11-unable-to-change-navigation-bar-height

Comment: Thanks Its Working fine. Navigation bar Height is changed but title not showing vertically center @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: hide this        `self.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(11, for: UIBarMetrics.default)`  and try

Comment: Yes. I removed. But stil its not showing vertically center

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940352/how-to-increase-the-height-of-navigation-bar-in-xcode/31940514?noredirect=1#comment79948647_31940514

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I check that one. but still bar button showing top of the navgation bar.