# iOS11 customize navigation bar height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios11

First of all, thank you for coming here and help solving my problem. Thank you!!!

In iOS11 beta6, `sizeThatFits:` seems to not work on UINavigationBar. I notice that UINavigationBar structure has changed by Reveal my app.

I have tried my best to change custom navigation bar's height. But it seems always to be `44`, and it works before iOS11.

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 64);
    return newSize;
}
```

[image]

Oddly, I just log its frame in `didMoveToSuperview` method, its height is 64, but I really see that is 44 in Reveal and app.

I have no idea about this... Help me please.. Thank you.

## Update:

I found that about my custom navigation bar LayoutConstraints log in console like this :

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x604000495ae0 FDCustomNavigationBar:0x7fe2f01399d0.(null) == 42>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x604000495b30 FDCustomNavigationBar:0x7fe2f01399d0.height == 44>"`
```

bug I even no use auto layout in my navigation bar. What's wrong with it?

## Update 8/28 :

[image]

I have set my custom navigation bar's subviews frame at navigation bar's `-
 layoutSubviews`method.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), 64);

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {

        if([NSStringFromClass([view class]) containsString:@"Background"]) {
            view.frame = self.bounds;
        } else if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) containsString:@"ContentView"]) {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin.y = 20;
            frame.size.height = self.bounds.size.height - frame.origin.y;
            view.frame = frame;
        }
    }
}
```

but the navigation bar will cover view controller's view. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387285/ios-11-navigation-bar-height-customizing

Comment: @SaurabhJain Thanks. I have seen it before I ask this question. That doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Jerry4me were you able to find a way to fix it? I'm facing the same issue and nothing works for me as well.

Comment: Here is my solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325181/ios-11-unable-to-change-navigation-bar-height

Answer (score 11):

Since iOS 11 UINavigationBar fully supports Auto Layout (this is the reason why you're seeing its constraints). I've opened a radar to Apple because I thought that setting a height constraint to the titleView would have adjusted the navigation bar height accordingly. However this is what Apple replied:

> Full support for auto layout does not imply that your view can influence other aspects of the layout of the navigation bar – in particular, the navigation bar enforces its own height and does not allow the title view or other custom views to exceed the height of the navigation bar.  We are continuing to work on this issue, and will follow up with you again.

As of today the radar is still open.

Comment: can you please share link of Apple.?

Comment: @MuhammadAhsanMaqsoodAwan unfortunately Apple's radars cannot be publicly accessed.

Comment: @emix Any workaround to fix this issue, how to dynamic the height of navigation bar which doesn't overlap on self.view?

Comment: @SureshDurishetti not actually. When I need a taller navigation bar I always hide the default one from the navigation controller and write my own custom view.

Comment: @emix means, have you ignored some top portion of self.view for that taller/custom navigation bar?

Comment: @SureshDurishetti yes. I have used it mainly with table/collection views, adjusting the content insets accordingly.

Comment: @emix Didn't they fix it yet?

Comment: @ZhebzhikBabich nope, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Hello I just experienced this same issue.

Now the top layout guide is deprecated on iOS 11. You have to reference the safeAreaLayoutGuide in your constraints.

Here's an example in swift

```
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
        let height = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! - CGFloat(12)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.yourTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide, constant: height)
        ])
    }
```

As you can see your view's top anchor should match the safeAreaLayoutGuide top anchor. In this example I'm using the variable height to create the new constraint. The variable height contains the navigation bar height minus a constant.

You should try by changing the height value.

Hope this helps you.