# Xamarin Forms Shell toolbar Height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer, xamarin.shell

I am new to Xamarin and was working on a few scenarios with Xamarin Forms Shell in Navigation bar. My requirement is to set Image to Navigation bar in shell. I am able to update the image in Navigation bar using Shell Custom Renderers for both android and ios. In Android, I was able to increase the height of the navigation bar/toolbar

In iOS, Image is not shown fully. I am currently facing an issue with setting the height of the navigation bar in iOS. Can someone help me with how to increase the height of toolbar (navigation bar) using shell custom renderers?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

**Unfortunately** , we can't modify the height of `NavigationBar` in iOS . We only can custom a toolbar view in iOS to do that . If using the default `NavigationBar` , Aplle not allows us to modify .

Have a look at this discussion : [iOS11 customize navigation bar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856474/ios11-customize-navigation-bar-height)