# iOS 11 Custom navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios11, navigationbar

I have a custom navigationBar that i create inside a viewController.
Before iOS 11 what i did was:

```
-(void)prepareNavigationbar{
[navigationBar removeFromSuperview];

float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if (version >= 7.0){
     navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
}
else{
   navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
}

navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
navigationBar.barStyle = 1;



if ([navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
{
    if (version>=7.0){
        UIImage *gradientImage44 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logostrip-568h"];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else{
        UIImage *gradientImage44 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-strip"];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }

}
else
{


    //NSLog(@"enter in to old version");
    [navigationBar drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
}


UINavigationItem *navigationItem    = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

[navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
}
```

The code works just fine until iOS 11.
Now the issue is that the custom background seems to be smaller then the navigationBar.

Note - I'm using xibs and i dont have any StoryBoard.

[image: The issue in View Debuger]

How can i fix it?

Comment: You have to change `UINavigationBarContentView` frame height in `layoutSubviews` of `UINavigationBar`.. and constrain it.

Comment: Thank you!
I search what you told me to do and i found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46251867/7259763
And it works just fine.
Thank you again for pointing me to the right direction