# UISearchBar scope buttons in UINavigationBar/UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add a UISearchBar to my UINavigationItem but the scope bar is showing behind the search bar. Any ideas to fix that problem?

iOS: 11.2
xCode: 9.2

my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    self.mySearchBar.delegate = self;
    self.mySearchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"item 1", @"item 2", @"item 3"];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.mySearchBar;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.mySearchBar setShowsScopeBar: TRUE];
    [self.mySearchBar setShowsCancelButton:TRUE animated:TRUE]; 
    return TRUE;
}
```

the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Context

The problem is that `UINavigationBar` provides a very specific and familiar iOS style that Apple wants to keep the same across apps. Default navigation bars don't expand to fit their contents.

When you set set the `titleView` of navigation item, you are expected to lay out the contents in that view based on the size of the navigation bar, not the other way around.

### Solutions

There are several possible solutions:

1. [Change the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387285/ios-11-navigation-bar-height-customizing?rq=1) of that instance of `UINavigationBar` (not recommended).
2. Place the `UISearchBar` underneath the navigation bar as a regular subview.
3. Use `UISearchController`

The first option should definitely not be your first solution because it requires you to solve *many* thorny issues. Use as a last resort.

Option 2 requires the following code changes. Replace `self.navigationItem.titleView = self.mySearchBar` with:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.mySearchBar];
UILayoutGuide *guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
[self.mySearchBar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor].active = YES;
[self.mySearchBar.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.rightAnchor].active = YES;
[self.mySearchBar.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.leftAnchor].active = YES;
```

And you are also missing code to resize the `UISearchBar` after showing the scope bar. The view does not resize itself. So, in your `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:` method, add this line just before return: `[self.mySearchBar sizeToFit];`

The third solution may be easier for you depending on your use case. That is, use `UISearchController`, which includes it's own `UISearchBar` anchored at the top of the screen. It would look just like solution #2 above as shown in the image below:

[image]

[Here is a great tutorial](https://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/) on using `UISearchController` if you are interested.