# Expanding UINavigationBar Height

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I followed along [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46592224/3320342) to get a bigger navigation bar working. The result is that it looks bigger, however not all elements of the bar actually expand, meaning that I can only interact with items places in the original size of the navigation bar. This is my pain point because I am trying to expand the UINavigationBar to put buttons in the expanded area and these can't be pressed.

Here's my code:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    var customHeight: CGFloat = 88

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: 100, height: 44))
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(button)    
    }

    @objc func buttonAction() {
        print("button pressed")
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: customHeight)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        for subview in self.subviews {
            var stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)
            if stringFromClass.contains("UIBarBackground") {
                subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: customHeight)
                subview.backgroundColor = .green
                subview.sizeToFit()
            }
            stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)
            if stringFromClass.contains("UINavigationBarContentView") {
                subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: customHeight)
                subview.backgroundColor = .black
                subview.sizeToFit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the screenshot from that output:

[image]

You can see here that when I resized the `UIBarBackground` in the `layoutSubviews()` function, I made it green and set it to the custom height, which worked. However when I resized the `UINavigationBarContentView` and set its colour to black, the colour gets set fine, but the height stays at 44.

See a screen shot of the debug view hierarchy below and we see that there are actually **two** items that still have the original height of 44.

[image]

All of this means that I cannot press the button in the view at all. However, if I move it up a bit so that it is inside the 44 height, then I can press it.

Looking for some help as to how I can properly resize all aspects of this nav bar

**EDIT**

If I remove the `subview.sizeToFit()` from the `UInavigationBarContentView` it resizes it to the correct size. I also noticed that the overridden `sizeThatFits` is never called?

Answer (score 0):

i was try to change the height before but also i couldn't ,but 
i makes the custom navigation controller and am call it on the viewDidLoad and hide the native navigation controller by doing

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

and i display the custom in the same place and i put my views on this navigation controller also you can do animations on height this custom nav bar if you want

i hope this help you

Comment: This doesn't help, setting it to not be hidden isn't the issue. Also it shouldn't matter if I'm using a nav controller or just the bar.