# Issue with top margin of title in uinavigationbar ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I try to programmatically add UINavigationBar in my viewController, however I got the markup issue which makes my navigation bar title move to the top border of the safe area and I wonder how to move this title to the center of the navigation bar. I cannot find any margins, paddings or frame configurations for it. So my question is how to vertically center the content of UINavigationBar

This is the code of navigation bar creation:

```
  private lazy var navItem: UINavigationItem = {
        let item = UINavigationItem(title: R.string.localization.supportNavigationBarTittle())
        return item
  }()

  private lazy var navBar: UINavigationBar = {
        let bar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 60))
        bar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(CGFloat(70), for: UIBarMetrics.default)

        return bar
  }()
```

And in the `viewDidLoad` method I append my toolbar to the whole view

```
navBar.tintColor = .white
view.addSubview(navBar)
        
let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: R.image.crossIcon.name), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(selectorName(_:)))
doneItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 16, left: 8, bottom: 20, right: 8);
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneItem
navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
```

Unfortunately, I got this zero top margin title and I cannot even find the way of how to fix it.

[image]

P.S.

I am pretty new in ios development, so I can make a lot of stupid mistakes.

Comment: Instead of manually adding a navbar, just make a `UINavigationController` with your controller as root and present that one instead (and set the title - which can be auto-set by the `title` property of your controller btw - and close button of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to replicate your view. If you want to refer to the code, you can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/2JEgv5pg). Ok, I think, even though you are setting the navbar to your custom height, the content will remain within the light green color area, which is the space for the content (which is `44pt` tall).

[image]

Adding to this, you are setting the `x & y` position of the navbar to `0` (i.e. you are aligning the navbar to the right and top). In iOS (or Android) you have a `SafeArea`, which in your case is the space with a red border in the following image.

[image]

So to make sure your navbar is away from the safe area, set the frame of the Nav bar in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method. See the following code

```
    private lazy var navBar: UINavigationBar = {
        let bar = UINavigationBar()
        return bar
    }()
    .
    .
    .
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.safeAreaInsets.top, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 60) // Setting the frame 
    }
```

The reason why you would add it to the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method is that when the `viewDidLoad` method is called the views/layout haven't been placed. This will result in the Navbar being moved below the safearea..

[image]

#### Important

Despite all of this, I would advise you to use a `UINavigationController` which by default has a `title` attribute that can be changes fairly easily.

##### Helpful links

If you want to read on how to increase the size of the UINavbar, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387285/ios-11-navigation-bar-height-customizing) thread

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, you helped me to understand my problem.